# DSLContext.ddl() doesn't seem to support types

Tags: jooq

I'm having a set of jOOQ classes generated with the jooq-codegen-maven plugin, that's cool! But when I want to use DSLContext to populate schema models by those classes by:

```java
        dslContext.ddl(Public.PUBLIC, new DDLExportConfiguration()
                .createSchemaIfNotExists(true)
                .createTableIfNotExists(true))
            .executeBatch();
```

It got an error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: type "my_type" does not exist
```

Debugging generated queries, I only see queries that creating schema and tables

JOOQ version: 3.12.4

Answer (score 1):

As per jOOQ 3.13, we don't support types (enums and others) in the jOOQ runtime meta model yet, so there's no way to re-create them from generated code or from other means. The relevant feature request is https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9509

The workaround is for you to implement your own mechanism to create these types at the appropriate moment.